# Using Declarative Bindings with API Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, knockout.js, wikipedia-api

I'm creating a tool which displays nearby points of interests on a map. When a marker is clicked the map should display a list of WikiPedia articles relating to that landmark.

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction as far as getting ko.observables working with my API return. I would like to avoid appending everything to the page like I am right now, I also believe it's causing some issues with my info windows not closing properly when another marker is clicked.

Some of the things I've tried was changing the $wikiData.append to an observable and then changing the contentString variable to include the data-bindings, but alas it did not work out.

The API I'm using is the WikiPedia API. Here is the code:

```
function mapPin(name, lat, long, text) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.lat = ko.observable(lat);
    this.long = ko.observable(long);
    this.text = ko.observable(text);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        map: mapView,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });



    function toggleBounce() {

        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }

    function article(content, url) {

        var self = this;
        self.content = content;
        self.url = url;

    }


    function apiData() {

        var wikipediaURL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + name + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';
        var wikiRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $wikiData.text ("Failed to get Wikipedia resources");
        }, 5000);

        $.ajax({

            url: wikipediaURL,
            dataType: "jsonp",

            success: function (response) {

                viewModel.articleList.removeAll();

                var articleList = response[1];

                for (var i = 0; i < articleList.length; i++) {
                    articleStr = articleList[i];
                    var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + articleStr;
                    viewModel.articleList.push(new article(articleStr, url));
                }

                clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout);
            }
        });

    }

    var contentString = '<!-- ko foreach: articleList --><li><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: content"></a></li>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    google.maps.event.addListener(mapView, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        toggleBounce();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: text + contentString
        });

        infowindow.open(mapView, marker);
        apiData();
    });

}

var mapView = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(61.196148, -149.885577),
});


var viewModel = {

    articleList: ko.observableArray([]),

    pins: ko.observableArray([
        new mapPin("Alaska Communications", 61.196148, -149.885577, "test11"),
        new mapPin("Moose's Tooth", 61.190491, -149.868937, "test2")
    ]),

    // TODO

    query: ko.observable(''),


    search: function (value) {
        viewModel.pins[0].removeAll();

        for (var i in pins) {
            if (pins[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(valkue.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                this.pins.push(pins[i])
            }
        }
    }
};


// Initiates the viewModel bindings.

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You can find a working version of the site here:

http://jamesiv.es/projects/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your articleList should be an observableArray in your view model with a binding in the view for that.

```
var viewModel = {
    articleList: ko.observableArray([]),
    pins: ko.observableArray([
        new mapPin("Alaska Communications", 61.196148, -149.885577, "test11"),
        new mapPin("Moose's Tooth", 61.190491, -149.868937, "test2")
    ]),
};
```

First make a little DTO:

```
function article(content, url) {
  var self = this;
  self.content = content;
  self.url = url;
}
```

When you get the data back from our ajax call, first clear the array:

```
viewModel.articleList.removeAll();
```

Then just loop through and do something like this:

```
viewModel.articleList.push(new article(articleStr, url));
```

Do the formatting in your view with a binding like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: articleList -->
<li><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: content"></a></li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the response. I've implemented your changes and I'm pretty sure everything is working behind the scenes but I can't seem to get the articles to display on the tooltips. I feel like I'm missing something in the data-bind properties. Does it matter that I'm generating the data bound HTML when a tooltip is clicked?  I updated the code in the main post if that's helpful at all. Thanks again!

Comment: I don;'t see the view... are you injecting that contentStr into the html somewhere.somehow?

Comment: Yeap, when the Google Maps tooltip is pulled it populates the content with the string:          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: text + contentString
        });. When I inspect element on the tooltip the data-bind properties are present, yet no content displays.

Comment: You don't want to do that dynamically... just put that code right into the view directly. When you populate/repopulate the observableArray knockout will rebind that section and magically show your new data.

Comment: I'm seeing now... you need to move all your observables into the viewModel. Then just change your infowindow HTML to reference/bind to properties on your view model. You don't need any dynamic DOM generation in your javascript. Just change properties, and your bindings will do the rest.

Comment: I am certain you will have an a-ha moment soon when you see how this all should work.

Comment: Pretty sure you're on the money. I think it must have something to do with the info windows are generating because if I place the data bound HTML right into index.html it works just fine, but when they are placed within the info window it does not. Strange.

Comment: The infoWindow markup will need to be in the DOM before you call applyBindings or knockout won't know anything about it.